# How to perform Deep learning on pointcloud data 3D

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, point-clouds, lidar-data

I've an `h5` file which has `[r,g,b,x,y,z]` information for each point in the point cloud. The point cloud has labels stored in a `.bin` file. Each row has a corresponding label. This is a classification problem.
I'm stuck at data processing stage. How to train/test split 700k rows? Also, this is one file, I have to include other h5 files also for training. Whats the best approach to such a problem? I'm trying to run `PointNet++` with this data to get classification.